# Setup AWS Wordpress server for local access by SSH Tunnel Fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, debian, ssh-tunnel

Steps taken:

1. Installed Debian Buster and Wordpress (Aws Lightsail own version).
2. Firewall restrict http and https access to only 127.0.0.1
3. Setup Putty tunnel with SSH port 22 (privatekey)
4. Putty SSH Tunnel Source port:9999 and Dynamic
5. Enter http://127.0.0.1:9999/ in chrome (Windows 10). Answer:
   127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

Access direct to IP by internet works if I open firewall. But not by tunnel.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your Putty tunnel setup. Selecting Dynamic port forwarding is for when you want to use Putty as a SOCKS proxy, and doesn't mean that the local port is forwarded as you expect.

Instead, I'd suggest configuring PuTTY with local/Auto port forwarding. Then you enter the port on your *local* machine and the port on the *remote* machine to forward to (which should probably be 80). Then you should be able to open the local port in your browser.